# Old fashioned grammar structure?　「きいてみたくてならなかった」

Tags: grammar

I just read the short story 高瀬舟 and I got a bit confused by this sentence:

> ［...］庄兵衛、まだどこやらに腑に落ちぬものが残っているので、なんだかお奉行さまにきいてみたくてならなかった。

In particular the last part of it, きいてみたくてならなかった

きいてみたい + くて + なる-in-negative-past-tense-form

In this some old fashioned form of きいかなくてはならない ? 
By the flow of the story I claim it means something like "I have to ask the magistrate ...", but I am not entirely sure if this is really correct.

Comment: Did you copy this correctly?  (I know the answer to that question but I want you to check it yourself.)  The「お奉行さまにきてみたくてならなかった」part makes no sense.  Since that is the part your question is about, I had to mention it here.

Comment: An い was missing, sorry

Comment: Good, that is what I meant and that is why the "Best Answer" below is invalid.  The base verb here is 「聞く」, not 「来る」.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is neither old-fashioned nor a form of きかなくてはならない.

This form of ～てならない means "really, really ～".  It is similar to the forms ～てしかたがない・～てしょうがない・～てたまらない.  Here are a few examples:

> - ワープロを始めたせいか、この[頃]{ごろ}目が疲れ**てしょうがない**　→　It might be because I started using a word processor, because lately my eyes are *really* tired.
> - いよいよあした帰国かと思うと、嬉しく**てしかたがありません**　→　Thinking about finally returning to my home country tomorrow, it make me *super* happy.
> - どうしたんだろう。今日は朝からのどが渇い**てたまらない**　→　What's happening?  Since this morning I've been *really, really* thirsty.
> - あの人はどうも悪いことを考えているのではないかという気が**してならない**　→　I *really* get the feeling that that guy is somehow thinking about something bad.

This is just きいてみたい in the paste tense of this form:  きいてみたくてならなかった.  So it is says something like "...for some reason I *really* wanted to ask you, Mr. Magistrate."

Note that the **て** here is *extremely* important for the meaning.  If it were just きいてみたくならなかった, it would say "I did not become wanting to ask you" which is almost the opposite meaning.

---

All examples taken from *どんな時どう使う日本語表現文型５００中・上級*

Comment: Are you aware that we do not say 「Person + に + くる」 to mean "to come see (someone)"?   Your answer is based on the non-fact that we do.

Comment: Apparently the original post had a typo in it, and *had* it been くる, I failed to remember that you don't say `Personにくる`, but instead need ところ to convey that. (`Personのところにくる`).  Hope that clears things up.